# I get this message when trying to run pod install in react-native ios folder [!] Invalid `Podfile` file: unexpected token at 'TypeError

Tags: react-native, compiler-errors, cocoapods, podfile, podfile-lock

Thats the error message I get when trying to run pod install, I have tried almost everything my podfile is correctly set up, I have upgraded everything to the latest version, I hope someone can help me, thanks for your time

error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'configurations').

[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: unexpected token at 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'configurations')

```
at Object.dependencyConfig (/Users/macbook/Desktop/sap_2/szigetkozapp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/build/config/index.js:102:37)

at /Users/macbook/Desktop/sap_2/szigetkozapp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-config/build/loadConfig.js:35:61

at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)

at getDependencyConfig (/Users/macbook/Desktop/sap_2/szigetkozapp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-config/build/loadConfig.js:31:51)

at Object.get @gorhom/bottom-sheet [as @gorhom/bottom-sheet] (/Users/macbook/Desktop/sap_2/szigetkozapp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-config/build/loadConfig.js:101:20)

at /Users/macbook/Desktop/sap_2/szigetkozapp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-config/build/commands/config.js:15:51

at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)

at filterConfig (/Users/macbook/Desktop/sap_2/szigetkozapp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-config/build/commands/config.js:14:38)

at Object.func (/Users/macbook/Desktop/sap_2/szigetkozapp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-config/build/commands/config.js:25:32)

at Command.handleAction (/Users/macbook/Desktop/sap_2/szigetkozapp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:111:23)
```

'.

## from /Users/macbook/Desktop/sap_2/szigetkozapp/ios/Podfile:7

## -------------------------------------------

## target 'SzigetkozApp' do

> config = use_native_modules!

## -------------------------------------------

I have tried deleting node_modules and install back with yarn install and npm i --legacy-peer-deps but didnt work
I have also tried to make a Gemfile and specify the cocoapods version and didnt work